# In Mac OS how do I disable the Apple menu bar from sliding down while in Full Screen; or set the hover time to be a longer duration

Tags: macos, mac, settings, menu-bar

I see the topic has been brought up a few times, but since there does not seem to be a workaround, I am wondering if I can set the hover time to be a longer duration.

Comment: Please elaborate? Are you talking about the top navigation bar? If so, I am pretty sure it hides it by default.

Comment: @Rushil Yes it's hidden, OP is asking how to prevent/slow down it being shown when moving the mouse up there.